# For the given quadratic equation find the value of p

Tags: quadratics

For the equation **3x^2 + px + 3 = 0** , **p>0**, if one of the roots is square of the other, then p is equal to?

Solving the equation, i get the value of p as **-6** but the question states that **p>0**. Is there another way of solving this or is the question wrong?

Comment: I agree with you; I think the question has a mistake.

Comment: @user84413: You can consider complex roots and then $p>0$ is possible.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks - I should have realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The value is $p=3$.**

Proof: Let $a, a^2$ be the roots of the equation. Then you get
$$3x^2+px+3 = 3(x-a)(x-a^2) = 3x^2-3(a^2+a)x+a^3,$$
So you first have to solve $a^3=1$. This gives the three solutions (the three cube-roots of unity)
$$a_1=1,\quad a_2=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3},\quad a_3=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}$$
which in turn give the possible values for $p$
$$p_1 = -3(a_1^2+a_1) = -6$$
$$p_2 = -3(a_2^2+a_2) = 3$$
$$p_3 = -3(a_3^2+a_3) = 3$$
$p_1\;$ is your negative value, but $p_2=p_3=3\;$ is positive and therefore $p=3\;$ is **the** answer to the question.

Comment: Wow!Thanks a lot gammatester :)